# Symfony 3.4 error page in prod mode is shown as dev. Shared hosting

Tags: symfony, shared-hosting, symfony-3.4

I have symfony 3.4 app which is deployed to shared hosting. My web root is public_html, so I am redirecting all requests to /web/ with .htaccess file.

These are the .htaccess combinations I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

But with any of them I get 404 error page as using dev environment. I have deleted app_dev.php file from the server.

This is my app.php 10 line :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

If I set second parameter to false, I receive 500 error. I can not see that error by myself so I am waiting for reply from hosting provider. Is my problem in app.php or .htaccess?

Comment: From a security perspective: if possible you should change the "documentroot" of the website to the `web` directory. Otherwise you risk exposing the config and `vendor` directory. Most current hosting-cpanels allow this. Regarding the actual problem: have you checked the log files from symfony?

Comment: @vstm, thank you. I don't know why, but I thought that this error was related with server configuration and will not be logged in symfony logs. The problem was in cached database credentials. I contacted my hosting provider and they said, that I can not change DocumentRoot from control panel.